# auto-start app minimized from Windows 8 registry

Tags: windows, registry

I need to be able to start a command line app minimized, and have it auto-start on Windows 8.1 at user login.

The following command works well at the Windows 8.1 command line:

```
start /min /D c:\"program files (x86)"\mycompanyname myappname.exe
```

However it fails to work in the registry at HKCU\software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.

Help please

Answer (score 0):

Option #1:

```
cmd.exe /c "start /min /D c:\"program files (x86)"\mycompanyname myappname.exe"
```

However you might see a black window popup and then go away.

Option #2: instead of changing registry, create a shortcut in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` In the properties of the shortcut, you can specify "Minimized" option.

Option #3: write a startMinimized.vbs script like this one (untested):

```
set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run "c:\program files (x86)\mycompanyname\myappname.exe", 2
```

Then in the registry

```
wscript.exe "c:\program files (x86)\mycompanyname\startMinimized.vbs"
```

Comment: cmd.exe /c "start /min /D c:\"program files (x86)"\mycompanyname myappname.exe" works.  NOTE that there are only one set of quotes around the 'program files (x86)' part.  Two sets of quotes do not work.

Comment: OK, corrected. I thought double set is necessary because escaping.

Comment: The ultimate answer to auto-start my app at user login time without any annoying window flash is to run it from HKCU:software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run as wscript.exe c:"program files (x86)"\mycompanyname\invisible.vbs C:\"program files (x86)"\mycompanyname\startup.bat where invisible.vbs looks like CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False